# Determining whether a dll is present or not

Tags: .net, file, exists, createobject

I want to use DotNet-dlls within VBA code. But I want to be able to determine whether a dll is present or not before I declare the object with CreateObject.

Is it possible to use a dotnet dll without using Regasm?

I have a MS Access database and I simply want to put the dll into the same directory as the mdb file.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are two questions in one here.  I will try to answer the second one.  I recently built a .net DLL for Crystal Reports for ms-access and tested out the COM interface on a computer that didn't have Regasm.  I found this link to be the most useful.
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/
It shows how to create an msi installer.